# How do you make a certain block of code run based on user input?

Tags: java

For the second choice part the user to types true or false. If they type "true" one thing happens and if they type "false" another thing happens. This part is fine.

My problem lies in the third choice part. I want the same thing that happened in the second choice part to happen but, I also want the second choice part to influence it. For example if the user typed "true" for both board and flee then this happens:

```
if(flee == true ) {
System.out.println("As you try to flee the Destroyer opens fire and you barely escape intact.");
System.out.println("This is the current level of your most vital systems: ");
System.out.println("Shield Level: 0%");
System.out.println("Ammunition Level: 0%");
System.out.println("Fuel Level: 5%");
System.out.println("Oxygen Level: 10%"); 
System.out.println("After your close call you go to the nearest heavy repair depot.");
if(board = true) {
System.out.println("Now repairing shield");
    for (Shield = 0; Shield <= 100; Shield += 50) {
        System.out.println(Shield + "%");
    }
    System.out.println("Shields repaired");
    System.out.println("Now replenishing ammunition");
    for (Ammunition = 0; Ammunition <= 100; Ammunition += 50) {
        System.out.println(Ammunition + "%");
    }
    System.out.println("Ammunition replenished");
    System.out.println("Now refueling");
    for (Fuel = 5; Fuel <= 100; Fuel += 5) {
        System.out.println(Fuel + "%");
    }
    System.out.println("Fueling complete");
    System.out.println("Now replenishing oxygen levels");
    for (Oxygen = 10; Oxygen <= 100; Oxygen += 10) {
        System.out.println(Oxygen + "%");
    }
    System.out.println("Oxygen replenished");
    }
```

And if they type "false" for flee and true for board then something else would happen.

```
//2nd choice
System.out.println("With all of your vital systems back to 100% you head to planet X34.");
System.out.println("As you approach X34 a massive cargo ship appears and you receive an invitation to dock and come aboard the ship.");


System.out.println("Do you board? True or False");
Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean board = scanner1.nextBoolean();

//board yes
if(board = true & board != false) {
    System.out.println("After docking and boarding the cargo ship the captain of the ship comes up to you");
    System.out.println("Captain: Welcome aboard I am Captain Skrull, here is card which allows for the fastest repairs available as a token of our friendship");
    System.out.println("You: Thank you so much");
    System.out.println("Skrull: You're welcome, now let us feast");
}
//board no
else {
    System.out.println("After declining the invitation the cargo ship locks its weapons on you because you didn't accept");
    System.out.println("The cargo ship and you battle until your ship is critically damaged and must flee for urgent repairs.");
    System.out.println("This is the current level of your most vital systems: ");
    System.out.println("Shield Level: 0%");
    System.out.println("Ammunition Level: 0%");
    System.out.println("Fuel Level: 10%");
    System.out.println("Oxygen Level: 15%"); 
    System.out.println("After barley escaping you head to the nearest repair depot to fix your ship.");
    System.out.println("Now repairing shield");
    for (Shield = 0; Shield <= 100; Shield += 10) {
        System.out.println(Shield + "%");
    }
    System.out.println("Shields repaired");
    System.out.println("Now replenishing ammunition");
    for (Ammunition = 0; Ammunition <= 100; Ammunition += 5) {
        System.out.println(Ammunition + "%");
    }
    System.out.println("Ammunition replenished");
    System.out.println("ERROR: DUE TO EXTENSIVE DAMGE FUEL TANK HAS BEEN DAMAGED. YOU CAN NOW HOLD ONLY 90% OF MAX FUEL.");
    System.out.println("Now refueling");
    for (Fuel = 10; Fuel <= 90; Fuel += 5) {
        System.out.println(Fuel + "%");
    }
    System.out.println("Fueling complete");
    System.out.println("Now replenishing oxygen levels");
    for (Oxygen = 15; Oxygen <= 100; Oxygen += 5) {
        System.out.println(Oxygen + "%");
    }
    System.out.println("Oxygen replenished");
}



//3rd choice
System.out.println("After your encounter with Captain Skrull you head to the are between the planets X70, Z70, and Y70 also known as the Bermuda triangle of space to investigate. ");
System.out.println("As you approach the Bermuda triangle of space the feared warship called the Destroyer appears. Your scanners show that multiple weapons are locked on to you.");

System.out.println("Do you flee? (True or False)");
Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean pop = scanner2.nextBoolean();
boolean flee = Boolean.valueOf(pop);



//flee yes
if(flee == true ) {
    System.out.println("As you try to flee the Destroyer opens fire and you barely escape intact.");
    System.out.println("This is the current level of your most vital systems: ");
    System.out.println("Shield Level: 0%");
    System.out.println("Ammunition Level: 0%");
    System.out.println("Fuel Level: 5%");
    System.out.println("Oxygen Level: 10%"); 
    System.out.println("After your close call you go to the nearest heavy repair depot.");
    if(board = true) {
    System.out.println("Now repairing shield");
        for (Shield = 0; Shield <= 100; Shield += 50) {
            System.out.println(Shield + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Shields repaired");
        System.out.println("Now replenishing ammunition");
        for (Ammunition = 0; Ammunition <= 100; Ammunition += 50) {
            System.out.println(Ammunition + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Ammunition replenished");
        System.out.println("Now refueling");
        for (Fuel = 5; Fuel <= 100; Fuel += 5) {
            System.out.println(Fuel + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Fueling complete");
        System.out.println("Now replenishing oxygen levels");
        for (Oxygen = 10; Oxygen <= 100; Oxygen += 10) {
            System.out.println(Oxygen + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Oxygen replenished");
        }
    else if (board = false){
        System.out.println("Now repairing shield");
        for (Shield = 0; Shield <= 100; Shield += 10) {
            System.out.println(Shield + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Shields repaired");
        System.out.println("Now replenishing ammunition");
        for (Ammunition = 0; Ammunition <= 100; Ammunition += 5) {
            System.out.println(Ammunition + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Ammunition replenished");
        System.out.println("Now refueling");
        for (Fuel = 5; Fuel <= 90; Fuel += 5) {
            System.out.println(Fuel + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Fueling complete");
        System.out.println("Now replenishing oxygen levels");
        for (Oxygen = 10; Oxygen <= 100; Oxygen += 5) {
            System.out.println(Oxygen + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Oxygen replenished");

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("User Error");
    }
}
else if (flee = false){
    System.out.println("Both you and the Destroyer open fire and engage in fierce battle which results in your oxygen levels to be depleted and the Destroyers weapon system to get destroyed");
    System.out.println("This is the current level of your most vital systems: ");
    System.out.println("Shield Level: 20%");
    System.out.println("Ammunition Level: 0%");
    System.out.println("Fuel Level: 25%");
    System.out.println("Oxygen Level: 0%"); 
    System.out.println("After the battle ends you head to the nearest repair depot and medical center for repairs and treatment for longterm low oxygen levels");
    if (board = true) {
    System.out.println("Now repairing shield");
        for (Shield = 20; Shield <= 100; Shield += 20) {
            System.out.println(Shield + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Shields repaired");
        System.out.println("Now replenishing ammunition");
        for (Ammunition = 0; Ammunition <= 100; Ammunition += 50) {
            System.out.println(Ammunition + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Ammunition replenished");
        System.out.println("Now refueling");
        for (Fuel = 25; Fuel <= 100; Fuel += 25) {
            System.out.println(Fuel + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Fueling complete");
        System.out.println("Now replenishing oxygen levels");
        for (Oxygen = 0; Oxygen <= 100; Oxygen += 50) {
            System.out.println(Oxygen + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Oxygen replenished");
        }
    else if (board = false){
        System.out.println("Now repairing shield");
        for (Shield = 20; Shield <= 100; Shield += 10) {
            System.out.println(Shield + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Shields repaired");
        System.out.println("Now replenishing ammunition");
        for (Ammunition = 0; Ammunition <= 100; Ammunition += 5) {
            System.out.println(Ammunition + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Ammunition replenished");
        System.out.println("Now refueling");
        for (Fuel = 25; Fuel <= 90; Fuel += 5) {
            System.out.println(Fuel + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Fueling complete");
        System.out.println("Now replenishing oxygen levels");
        for (Oxygen = 0; Oxygen <= 100; Oxygen += 5) {
            System.out.println(Oxygen + "%");
        }
        System.out.println("Oxygen replenished");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("User Error");
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("User Error");
}
```

Comment: You need to give *much* more information about what you're trying to do. This is painfully vague.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking, but please be aware that you've provided a lot of code with *no* explanation, and no sign of having tried to reduce it to a [mcve]. I would say that `if (board = true)` looks distinctly dodgy - are you aware that `=` is the assignment operator, whereas `==` is for equality testing?

Comment: When I run it the true part works but not the false part. Also, the do you board part work fine.

Comment: `if(board = true & board != false)` Ouch... one equal is assignement, not comparison. And use two `&` so you don't evaluate unnecessary expressions. And add some description of your problem, not just your code.

Comment: `if(board = true & board != false)` -- the number of things wrong with this one little snippet of code is quite impressive.

Comment: I'm surprised no one noticed that `if (flee == true)` is unnecessary anyway x) You can just use `if(flee)`

Comment: Sorry did not have enough space to write what I am doing in the title. I am trying to make the do you board part affect the flee part. So, if the user inputed that they did board and they did flee then this block of code will execute

Comment: A boolean can't _be_ neither true nor false. You can remove the else statements, and change the else if statements to else statements.

Comment: The block of code that will execute is the if (flee = true) and the if (board = true) part

Comment: Add your further explanations as an edit to the actual question and not as comments.

Comment: Sorry brand new to coding

Comment: `board = true` is *assignment*, **not** comparison. `if (board = true)` is trivially true.

Comment: Is this any better???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statements won't work how you expect them to to. Let's take an example to see why:

```
if(board = true & board != false)
```

This has a number of problems:

1. You don't need to explicitly compare to `true` and `false`. Doing so is considered bad style. `if (board)` is exactly equivalent to `if (board == true)`.
2. `board = true` is *assignment*, not comparison. You actually have this mistake in several places. This is one of the main reasons your `if` statements aren't working how you expect: `if (board = true)` *can't possibly* be false, so the `else` statement can't possibly run. Check your code carefully for other cases where you've confused `=` and `==` (there are several).
3. `if (board == true && board != false)` is redundant and may represent a misunderstanding of how `boolean` values work. If `(board == true)`, then of *course* `board != false`. Think about what it would mean if `board == true && board == false`; under what conditions could something like this *possibly* be true? Keep in mind that, by definition, `boolean` values are *either* `true` *or* false (but not both and certainly not some third value); there are only 2 possible choices.

I'd definitely encourage you to review how comparison works in Java as well as taking a look at [this rather excellent article on debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You particularly want to focus on learning how and where to set breakpoints (i.e. points where the IDE will pause execution and allow you to examine your program's state) and how to step through your code (i.e. run your program one line at a time so you can see the effect of each line of code) with a debugger.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did what you suggested and it works fine now and I will now keep the difference between = and == in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to programming!

In Java, the `=` sign, or operator, is used for assignment, meaning whatever is on the right side of the `=` will be saved to whatever is on the left side of it.

The sign you want is `==`. The `==` sign is a comparison sign, which is primarily used for booleans (variables which hold either `true` or `false`)

Based on your comments, I would say you should simply avoid remembering this for now by encasing the parts which follow the boarding in their own block of code. This way, you will only execute the flee check if the player decided to board the ship.

For example:

```
// Prompt user to see if they want to board, capture input.
  if (board) {
    adventurePostBoarding();
  }
```

And define your method below as such:

```
private final void adventurePostBoarding() {
  // TODO code here
}
```

In the future, remember to compare `true` and `false` values using `==`, and not `=`.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved by some explanation of why this fixes the problem, especially since the OP is new to programming. For example, it *does* technically fix the primary problem (the fact that the OP confused `=` and `==`), but this doesn't explain that that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll edit my answer to include that.